Joining measures from two fact tables
Started my BI journey two days ago and got stuck with this “issue”.
I have a fact table representing order intake (consists of invoices and sales orders related to a project -multiple rows with same project) and an additional fact table representing projects (dates, budgets, actual ect)
So i would like to group and sum the order intake pr. Project and by project sales and current-forecast margin (table 2).
Resulting In a KPI card showing total order intake amount and corresponding sales and forecast %
Hope it makes sense
Thought abount merging to one table - but from what i Read this is not recommended

Can you please provide some sample data, expected output, or a file so we may replicate this issue?
